# Linux equivalent of GetCommandLine and CommandLineToArgv?

Tags: c, linux, api

I wonder if there are some API to get the current process' command line arguments on Linux.

---

I guess I was terribly unclear. The real purpose of the question was about passing unicode file names through command line arguments.

Comment: `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, and you have in `argc` the number of arguments, and `argv` is an array of `char` pointers containing the arguments.  This is ANSI C, so will work on any portable implementation.  Or do you want command line options parsing?

Comment: I see. I was aware of the argc argv paradigm. I wonder how I could get unicode arguments through argv.

Comment: argv will give you whatever the shell put in there; since the shell just treats it as a byte string, that pushes it back to the terminal.  All the common terminals now are unicode capable, so it should just work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Read from file `/proc/self/cmdline`

For example:

```
[wallyk@zf ~]$ od -a /proc/30651/cmdline
0000000   /   u   s   r   /   s   b   i   n   /   h   t   t   p   d nul
0000020
```

Or, for a satisfyingly refreshing self-reference:

```
[wally@zf images]$ od -c /proc/self/cmdline
0000000   o   d  \0   -   c  \0   /   p   r   o   c   /   s   e   l   f
0000020   /   c   m   d   l   i   n   e  \0
0000031
```

Comment: Be careful of the null bytes (0x00) delimiting each token. Also, the text in /proc/self/cmdline will not be exactly what the user typed -- quotation marks will be stripped, etc.

Comment: Also be careful that currently the `/proc` interface only shows the first page (4k) of the command line, even though it may be longer (I believe up to 32 pages).

Answer (score 3):

Linux doesn't do "Unicode filenames" per se. All filenames are just random sequences of 8-bit characters as far as the kernel is concerned.

Bad things can happen, like the user can write a file and then change their locale, leaving their filename encoded in the previous locale. So if you're taking a filename as input, you need to preserve the exact 8-bit byte sequence passed to you in main(). If you need to display it to the user, try to interpret it in the encoding of the current locale and convert to your favorite type of Unicode.

On many modern Linux systems, the encoding will be UTF-8 so this will generally work OK.

Answer (score 2):

checkout [Getopt](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html) It's a command line parsing library that's implemented in many languages including C.

Otherwise:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

`argv` is an array of arguments as `char*` and `argc` is the number of arguments.

`argv[0]` is always the executable filename itself.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `argc` and `argv`.  `argv` will be in the local encoding (which could be UTF-8), and from there you can convert to `wchar_t` (e.g. via `mbtowc`).