# Why does this freestanding program segfault?

Tags: c++

I've found an interesting behavior that I cannot explain. I wrote this very simple program that segfaults without apparent reason. Please, can someone explain what is happening here?

- The program is run in Ubuntu (I don't know if that matters).
- No includes, no libraries, no link to stdlib. No dependencies whatsoever.

I've tested that the segfault goes away when any of the following happens:

- stdlib is linked (and renamed `_start` to `main`, removed extern "C", etc.)
- GCC is used
- Optimizations are enabled

The following is the one and only code file for the program, lets call it `main.cpp`.

Build it with: `clang main.cpp -nostdlib`.

```
struct A
{
    A () = default;
    A (const A &) = default;
    // A (A &) = default;

    char * a = nullptr;
    unsigned long long b;
};

struct ConvertibleToA
{
    ConvertibleToA() = default; // default constructor
    operator A() { return m_a; } // conversion to type A
    A m_a;
};

extern "C"
void _start()
{
    ConvertibleToA my_convertible{};
    A my_a = my_convertible;
}
```

Comment: I'd try to find the startup code source that you are deliberately not linking and figure out what the functions it is performing are & if they are needed for your program. Segment register setup comes to my mind, but I am not acquainted with startup code for a program running under Linux.

Comment: Another problem you're going to have, if you continue this route, is that global and static constructors and destructors won't run.

Comment: For the ABI, _start is not a function with normal C calling conventions. You need to use (inline) assembly. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58806696/gcc-optimizer-generating-error-in-nostdlib-code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your stack alignment.
For the SysV ABI, `rsp` is guaranteed to be 16-bytes aligned at program entry. However, a normal function expect `rsp` to be 16-bytes+8 aligned, because of the address pushed by `call`.

Clang uses SSE aligned instructions which will crash, GCC doesn't.

Comment: That was it! Finally made it work. The first thing my C++-coded `_start` function does is push `rbp` (perhaps compiler doesn't know that's the entry point?). That broke 16-bytes alignment. The only reason the program worked with optimizations is that the compiler removed everything, because nothing was volatile nor had visible effects (no syscalls).
Fixed it by aligning `rsp` (by and-ing it) just before the function calls.
Thanks a lot. I would have had a hard time figuring that out.