# Linux getting terminal arguments from _start not working with inline assembly in C

Tags: c, x86-64, inline-assembly

I am trying to write my own _start function using inline assembly. But when I try to read argc and argv from stack (%rsp and %rsp + 8) I get wrong values. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <syscall.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("%d\n", argc);
    printf("%s\n", argv[0]);
    printf("got here\n");
    return 0;
}

void _start() {
    __asm__(
    "xor %rbp, %rbp;"
    "movl (%rsp), %edi;"
    "lea 8(%rsp), %rsi;"
    "xor %rax, %rax;"
    "call main"
...
```

Terminal:

```
$ gcc test.c -nostartfiles
$ ./a.out one two three
0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$
```

Any idea where my fault could be ?
I am using a Ubuntu 20.04 VM

Comment: Have you tried debugging it and getting the PC at which seg fault happens?

Comment: Seg fault happens because the adress in rsi (argv) is a random adress instead of what should be a pointer to ["one","two","three"], but in the System V abi it says that this pointer should be at $rsp + 8

Comment: If you are using `-nostartfiles`, then most likely the code which sets up processing of command line arguments is not called at all.

Comment: @scrutari: You're thinking of Windows.  On Unix systems (and GNU/Linux), command args aren't a flat string, they're already separated (as passed to `execve` by the shell or whatever) with `argc` and `argv[]` on the stack on entry to user-space.  This looks correct for a minimal `_start:` if the OP didn't put it inside a non-`naked` C function that will use the stack before the asm statement. [How Get arguments value using inline assembly in C without Glibc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50260855). Never use GNU C Basic asm statements in a non-naked function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks correct for a minimal `_start:` but you put it inside a non-`naked` C function.  Compiler-generated code will run, e.g. `push %rbp` / `mov %rsp, %rbp`, before execution enters before the asm statement.  To see this, look at `gcc -S` output, or single-step in a debugger such as GDB.

Put your asm statement at global scope (like in [How Get arguments value using inline assembly in C without Glibc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50260855)) or use `__attribute__((naked))` on your `_start()`.  Note that `_start` isn't really a function

As a rule, never use GNU C Basic asm statements in a non-naked function.  Although you might get this to work with `-O3` because that would imply `-fomit-frame-pointer` so the stack would still be pointing at argc and argv when your code ran.

A dynamically linked executable on GNU/Linux will run libc startup code from dynamic linker hooks, so you actually *can* use `printf` from `_start` without manually calling those init functions. Unlike if this was statically linked.

However, your `main` tries to return to your `_start`, but you don't show `_start` calling `exit`.  You *should* call `exit` instead of making an _exit system call directly, to make sure stdio buffers get flushed even if output is redirected to a file (making stdout full buffered).  Falling off the end of `_start` would be bad, crashing or getting into an infinite loop depending on what execution falls in to.