# C _start dlopen SIGSEGV

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, dlopen, fasm

I'm using `-nostartfiles` flag (GCC) so my main function is :

```
void _start() {}
```

Now I want to use `dlopen()` function to open a `.so` lib ... So I decide to link the `libdl.so`
too (to access `dlopen()` and ...) ... In fact, my CMake is like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(myproject C)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
add_executable(myproject start.c)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-O3 -mavx2 -nostartfiles")
target_link_libraries(myproject 
        "libdl.so"
        "libc.so")
```

and this is my `start.c`

```
void * dlopen(const char * filename, int flag);

void _start() {
   
  void * lib = dlopen("mylib.so", RTLD_LAZY);
  if(!lib) {}

  // sys_exit(0)
  asm volatile("syscall" :: "a" (60), "D" (0) : "rcx", "r11");
}
```

As you see, I just used `dlopen()` function and when I run this program, I get 139 as exit-code and there is a problem with `dlopen()` function … There is a problem inside `_dl_relocate_object` function on `movaps %xmm0,-0x70(%rbp)` ... segmentation fault

But when I remove `-nostartfiles` and I change `void _start() {}` to `int main() {}`, everything is just fine ... How to fix this problem with `-nostartfiles` ? What is the problem !!?

**Attention, the `"mylib.so"` library MUST exist otherwise you get no error on `void _start() {}`**

***UPDATE
I test it in Assembly (FASM) and worked successfully without requiring any initialization !!!!!***

```
format ELF64 EXECUTABLE 3
entry start

include 'import64.inc'

interpreter '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2'
needed 'libdl.so'
import dlopen,dlsym

segment readable executable

start:
        mov     rdi, dl_filename
        mov     esi, 1
        call    [dlopen]

        mov     rdi, rax
        mov     rsi, dl_function_name
        call    [dlsym]

        call    rax

        mov     eax, 60
        xor     edi, edi
        syscall
        hlt

segment readable
dl_filename db 'libuntitled.so', 0x00
dl_function_name db 'hello', 0x00
```

Comment: What is the problem? - you can check an error code.

Comment: @user14063792468 well i said what is the problem ... i get segmentation fault in `_dl_relocate_object` function !

Comment: Really missed that. You can help by specifying your OS.

Comment: If you want to bypass all the C runtime initialization code ("-nostartfiles")... then you need to know what you're doing.  It sounds like you're trying to load a shared library ... using dlopen(), which is *ITSELF* part of a shared library ... without completely initialiizing the shared library runtime code first.  Whoops!

Comment: SUGGESTIONS: Q: Do you absolutely *NEED* to use "-nostartfiles"?  What exactly do you gain without it? Q: Do you have a static version of libdl.a you can link instead?  Q: Have you tried observing the default startup (e.g. with [strace](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) or equivalent) to see exactly what "initialization" you'll need to do "manually"?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to use `-nostartfiles`?

Comment: I must use `-nostartfiles` since i want to write Assembly project too without any C functions except (dlopen) ...

Comment: `gcc` on `Linux`, as is on every other system, uses some runtime initialization. That is, it links with some files, like `crt0.o`, `crt1.o`, that "tune up" the C runtime. You explicitly have that initialization off. Also you still link with the `libc`. And `libc` suggests that it will be some initialization. You will have to supply some initialization by yourself _before_ you can use `libc`.

Comment: `libdl` may also imply that you had done some initialization by yourself. I can not reproduce the program, I do not have `Linux` at hand. Seeing the `crt0`, or whatever startup it is, is a good start for you to understand what is what.

Comment: This looks like you have a Stack misalignment problem.  Make sure your Stack is aligned to 16 bytes whenever you call a function.

Comment: @paulsm4: A static library is the opposite of what you want.  You need to let Linux's dynamic linking infrastructure run init hooks in shared libraries (including libc) if you're replacing `_start` with your own code that doesn't directly call init functions.  The only way this program can work with most libc functions is by being dynamically linked (to libc at least).

Comment: The problem is that `_start` isn't a function, and is entered with RSP%16 == 0, not RSP%16 == 8 like functions are.  So you need to declare it appropriately with GNU C `__attribute__((force_align_arg_pointer))
`, or write it in asm.  Or compile with `-mincoming-stack-boundary=2` to make code that realigns the stack in every function.  [How Get arguments value using inline assembly in C without Glibc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50260855) shows that.

Comment: @PeterCordes your answer `__attribute__((force_align_arg_pointer))` was amazing and solved my problem ... yes i thought about stack alignment since the problem was from `movaps` ... Thank you ... but this question is unique since it's talk about `dlopen` not segmention fault problem anyway

Comment: The actual problem is writing a `_start` (in C or asm) that makes it safe to call other functions, including `dlopen` from `libdl`, or `printf` from `libc`.  As you said yourself, `__attribute__((force_align_arg_pointer))` is the key part of the answer, so it's a duplicate of Q&As that explain stack alignment and how to get it in this case (a `_start` written in C instead of asm).  What do you mean "*it's talk about `dlopen` not segmention fault problem anyway*" - the crash problem you describe in this question is a segmentation fault.  Stack alignment is how you broke `dlopen`.