# Why doesn't inline assembly need section directives like .data or .text

Tags: assembly, x86, inline-assembly

As a novice I am following tutorials. One is to capitalize all chars in a string, in inline assembly in VS 2022:

```
int main()
{
    char mystr[] = "Hello World:";

    _asm
    {
        mov ecx, length mystr
    my: cmp [mystr + ecx], 'a';
        jl nocap;
        cmp [mystr + ecx], 'z';
        ja nocap;
        sub [mystr + ecx], 32;

    nocap:
    loop my
    }

    std::cout << mystr;
```

My question is: Why does this assembly not need sections, such as .data, .text or _start:
There might be some mix of x86 asm and Linux asm in the examples.

Answer (score 6):

Because it's inline asm!  It's just inside the body of your C++ function, and the compiler chooses which section to put the machine code for functions into.  (`.text`).

You don't need section directives for the same reason C++ programs don't need manual section directives or GNU C `__attribute__((section(".text")))` - C++ compilers have working defaults for where to put stuff.

---

In fact MSVC doesn't even let you switch sections or use `db` to emit arbitrary bytes inside an `asm{}` block; it's not a full assembler because it has to parse and *understand* your asm to know what registers it might modify, so it knows what to save.

GNU C inline asm leave is up to you to tell the compiler what your inline asm's outputs/inputs/clobbers are, and lets you emit arbitrary text which the assembler will assemble.

GCC literally works by generating a `.s` text file and running `as` to assemble it.  GNU C inline `asm ("add %1, %0" : "=r"(dst) : "r"(src))` works kind of like a compile-time printf formatting custom text into that assembly file.  You *can* do stuff that would break the following compiler-generated code, like switching sections without using `.pushsection` / `.popsection` to come back to the section the compiler was in.  Or switching asm syntax to something other than what the compiler was using.

Or doing useful things like using `.pushsection .data` and emitting some bytes in `.data`, then coming back.  The Linux kernel makes some use of this.  e.g. in [arch/x86/asm/alternative.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4a57a8400075bc5287c5c877702c68aeae2a033d/arch/x86/include/asm/alternative.h#L38) they `.pushsection .smp_locks` to record the address of the `lock` prefix for atomic RMW instructions (using `.long` to emit 4 bytes), so if the kernel boots on a machine with only one CPU, it can patch those `lock` prefixes to `nop` or a dummy prefix, since the relevant instructions are all atomic wrt. interrupts, just not other CPUs that could be running at the same time.

---

**You also don't need to write your own `_start`** (the standard name for the process entry point in Linux) because the C++ compiler links your program with CRT startup code that provides one that calls `main` and exits with `main`'s return value if `main` returns.  If you wanted to write your own, you could in GNU C inline asm for Linux and use `gcc -nostdlib` (which implies `-nostartfiles`): [How Get arguments value using inline assembly in C without Glibc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50260855/how-get-arguments-value-using-inline-assembly-in-c-without-glibc)

For MSVC you'd need to use a separate `.asm` file; MSVC doesn't allow inline asm at global scope.  Or maybe you could use a `_declspec(naked)` function to define a WinMain or whatever the actual entry point is for an executable, with your hand-written asm instructions that do the necessary setup like calling standard library init functions, and then `call main` / `push eax` / `call ExitProcess` (or actually `call exit` to make sure cleanup happens, like flushing stdio buffers).

Comment: Thanks for a very detailed answer. I look forward to be able to distinguish all of this - which might take a while or two. Best wishes.

Comment: @mortenlund: Perhaps looking at the pure asm generated by the compiler would be informative; you can see what directives it uses when compiling your C++ (including the inline asm).  On https://godbolt.org/z/8bTWv9Pfv , right click on a C++ source line and "reveal linked code" to scroll past the noise of directives and stuff in MSVC's output from the header.  Or make a version of it that doesn't include anything or use `cout`, just the asm part and return, to simplify the asm output.

Comment: In that link I unchecked the "directives" filter so it would leave in lines like `_TEXT   SEGMENT` (that's MASM syntax, not GAS `.section .text` or NASM `section .text`).  See also [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)

Comment: It sounds very reasonable. I will look into that.  Thank you for sharing this with me. Your path is showing the exact same example as the tutorial. : )