# Why does this simple C program depend on the GCC optimization level?

Tags: c, x86, stack, forth

I came across this surprising tidbit while translating [jonesforth.s](http://git.annexia.org/?p=jonesforth.git;a=blob;f=jonesforth.S;h=45e6e854a5d2a4c3f26af264dfce56379d401425;hb=66c56998125f3ac265a3a1df9821fd52cfeee8cc) from x86 ASM to C with GCC extensions.  [depends_on_optimization.c](https://gist.github.com/jburgy/50902c66ec8d888b9d387cf858427647) is a "simple" C program which depends on whether it's compiled with (any `-O`) or without (`-O0`) optimizations.  It's entirely possible that the program invokes Undefined Behavior as it's using `_start(void)` instead of `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` then poking around the C stack to find `argc`.  That's an artefact of translating ASM to C.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NEXT goto **ip++
#ifdef __OPTIMIZE__
#define OFFSET 3
#else
#define OFFSET 0
#endif

void _start()
{
    intptr_t *stack[1024];
    register intptr_t **sp = stack + (sizeof stack / sizeof *stack), *p;
    register void **ip;

    goto _start;

ADD:
    p = *sp++;
    sp[0] += (intptr_t)p;
    NEXT;
LIT:
    *--sp = (intptr_t *)*ip++;
    NEXT;
S0:
    *--sp = (intptr_t *)(stack + (sizeof stack / sizeof *stack));
    NEXT;
EXIT:
    p = *sp++;
    exit(*p);

    static void *code[] = {&&S0, &&LIT, (void *)OFFSET, &&ADD, &&EXIT};
_start:
    ip = code;
    NEXT;
}
```

What compiler flag should I use to make GCC produce the same stack layout regardless of optimization level?  I tried various combinations of `-fno-stack-check`, `-fno-stack-protector`, and `-fno-stack-clash-protection` to no avail.

Comment: Please include your C code as text in the question, not a link to some external website which will be stale in the future.

Comment: That's a pretty nasty piece of code. Personally, I would throw it in the bin and start again by hand. For example, your stack is an array of (effectively) `int**` Why? It's the data stack, It should be an array of `int` - or ideally a fixed sized int like `int32_t`.

Comment: *then poking around the C stack to find argc* - It's making assumptions about the stack layout and how far past the end of `intptr_t *stack[1024];` it will find `argc`.  (Which was pointed at by the stack pointer on entry to `_start`. If you're on x86 (-64), that's where a return address arrives for functions, so you could just use `__builtin_return_address` to read the value.

Comment: [How Get arguments value using inline assembly in C without Glibc?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50283880) shows how to do that for the x86-64 SysV ABI, with some nasty hacks but will get GCC to make the asm we want without any inline `asm`, for any optimization level, without making assumptions about stack layout other than the ABI.  (Not that it's well-defined behaviour to take the address of a function arg and offset from there, though.)  For a RISC machine where the return address is passed in a link register (like ARM `lr`), that wouldn't work, but your `OFFSET` isn't portable either.

Comment: Anyway, the different in stack layout should be clear from looking at the asm: part of it is from `push rbp` to make a frame pointer, since `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` is only on at `-O1` and higher.  Without `-fstack-protector-strong`, GCC might put scalar locals above the array; you'd have to check.  With optimization, it'll keep them in registers so no stack space at all for them, unless you use `volatile`.  But that would still just be hard-coding an offset that happens to work with a specific compiler version and options, and could change in the future.

Comment: My recommendation would be to write a simple `_start` in asm that calls a `main` (as shown in other answers on the Q&A I linked), or let GCC link the CRT startup code so you can write a normal `main` that takes `argc`.  Nothing you can do with dead-reckoning and hard-coding offsets based on some GCC version's stack-frame layout choices is at all suitable for anything except local experiments to see if you read the asm correctly.  (See [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116) re: looking at asm.)

Comment: Re: what unoptimized code-gen looks like: [Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53366394) - every variable has its own address, and this isn't optimized away when you tell the compiler not to optimize.

Comment: It is one big Undefined Behaviour. Analyzing it makes little or no sense. if the output depends on optimizations - it is a sight of UB. Bin this garbage and write a proper one yourself

Comment: The only good reason I can think of to even consider translating assembly to C is to arrive at a more portable version of the original. In that case, however, the best way forward is to *rewrite* in (standard) C. Assembly code of any complexity generally does not have a direct translation into C.  Indeed, that's closely related to why C compilers have options for optimization.

Comment: You're spot on @JohnBollinger : see https://bur.gy/2023/02/24/what-forth-again.html for details of how translating jonesforth from assembly to C allowed me to compile it to WASM.  And to the folks who suggest a different approach: thanks for the suggestion but threaded code using GCC labels as values is the whole point.